# Strange behavior while returning csv file from spring controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cross-browser

I working in a spring application which have an action method that returns a CSV file.

This action works fine but in some cases it throws a predefined exception (`MyAppException`).

I have another method that is annotated `@ExceptionHandler(MyAppException.class)`

In the exception handler method I return another csv file but with different contents.

The code that returns the csv file is almost the same in the two methods.

```
List<String[]> list= new ArrayList<String[]>();
list.add(new String[]{
   integrationRequestErrorLog.getErrorMessage(),
   Long.toString(integrationRequestErrorLog.getId()),
   Integer.toString(integrationRequestErrorLog.getErrorCode())
});
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(response.getWriter(), ',');
writer.writeAll(list);
writer.close();
```

the difference between the two method is the list of contents.

In the first method the file is returned normally while in the exception handler method I have a strange behavior.

The exception handler method works fine with Opera browser while it gives me a 404 with FireFox.

Opera browser give me 404 also but it download the file while firefox does not?

Really I do not understand what is the difference here.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Content-Type HTTP header being set correctly on the response? Firefox and Opera probably handle things differently. And, I suspect the Spring exception handler is not setting it at all. You probably want to explicitly set it as `text/csv`.

Comment: Thnx AngerClown I have tried to add the content type to text/csv and the situation still the same :(. I have also changed the way in which I return the file (I have a static file on the disk, I read it and writ it to the response) and the situation still the same.